# Destroy all activities executed in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, process, kill, destroy

I'm doing a Google Maps based app with a Logout screen. The thing is, when I need to press de Logout button, the app return to the Home Screen, but it is still retrieving the location executed before. I need to close every single activity executed after clicking the Logout button.

I've tried plenty of things, like;

```
Intent i = new Intent(LogoutScreen.this, LogonScreen.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Or:

```
System.exit(0);
```

and executing the app again, but I don't like the result.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try this instead of `System.exit(0)`: `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())`

Comment: Neither of those are (good) solutions. Do you launch multiple tasks in your app? Try to avoid this.

Comment: So what should I do? The app has two modes, so from the beggining until the screen I use to select one of the two modes is Splash Screen - Login or Sign Up Screen - Screen to choose the mode. The thing is, I can open the other mode trough the one I've chosen at the beggining, but if I open the other mode, the last one is still running...

Answer (score 0):

If you subscribe to location updates in your activities/fragments, the good practice is to unsubscribe from all updates when `Activity` goes to background. 
Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Killing process or any other workaround is just a bad practice.